# How to order numeric and non-numeric values in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I was wondering how can I order numeric and non-numeric values using MySQL.

Here is what is outputed.

```
1
10
1234
2
25
26
a
b
c
d
```

Here is what I want.

```
1
2
10
25
26
1234
a
b
c
d
```

Here is my MySQL code.

```
SELECT tags.*, COUNT(tag_id) as number_of_tags 
FROM tags 
INNER JOIN posts_tags ON tags.id = posts_tags.tag_id
GROUP BY tags.tag
ORDER BY tags.tag ASC
```

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153633/natural-sort-in-mysql, I think you want a natural sort, which sadly does not exist in mysql yet.

Comment: Brandon I think that comment deserves to be an answer

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Natural Sort in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153633/natural-sort-in-mysql), I think you want a natural sort, which sadly does not exist in mysql yet.