# How make for order by name in MYSQL as with order name in Window

Tags: sql, mysql, natural-sort

table
Picture with rows have name

```
1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg,4.jpg,5.jpg,6.jpg,7.jpg,8.jpg,9.jpg,10.jpg,11.jpg
select * from Picture order by name
```

mysql order : `1.jpg,10.jpg,11.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg,......`

### Issue:

I want it sort all type name like as with Window `1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg,4.jpg,5.jpg,6.jpg,7.jpg,8.jpg,9.jpg,10.jpg,11.jpg`

and it must working with other case as

```
flower01.jpg,flower02.jpg,flower031.jpg,....,flower10.jpg
```

please help me

Comment: It uses alphabetical sort order. If you think about it, mysql is doing the right thing.

Comment: @klaus yeah, but it's still not really desirable in this case.  There doesn't seem to be an easy solution for this in mySQL. I'm surprised!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Natural Sort in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153633/natural-sort-in-mysql)

Comment: Lots more, maybe one contains a solution, I'm too lazy to sift through them: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+natural+sort

Answer (score 2):

You basically have 4 choices.

1. Change name to a numeric type, and remove the .jpg (adding it later in code)
2. Add an 'order' column and sort by that
3. Sort it in your code, not in SQL
4. Use of the of the cast 'hacks' (e.g. CAST(NAME AS UNSIGNED)

Answer (score 1):

A hackish way to do it:

```
... ORDER BY CAST(name AS UNSIGNED);
```

---

**Edit**: an alternative would be:

```
 ... ORDER BY LPAD(name,N,'0');
```

Where `N` is the maximum width of your column.
Sadly, MySQL doesn't support natural sorting natively AFAIK.

Comment: In all cases you mentioned: yes. In all cases where natural sorting could be handy: indeed no. See [the link Pekka provided](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+natural+sort)

Answer (score 0):

ODER BY name sees that name is a string and sorts it accordingly,charater by character. You have to make MySQL interpret the name as numeric value. A way might be something like this:

```
select * from Picture order by name * 1;
```

Comment: I find an explicit `CAST` preferable to this because of long-term maintenance: Somebody looking at the code in five years will not understand what the hell this was for :)