# How do I order by in mysql when the value are alpha numeric?

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

I need to order a queries results by the name which is a varchar(50) from the bundles table.
The table contains the following values for name:

```
# 'Package 1', 'Package 2', 'Package 3', 'Package 10' etc.
SELECT name FROM bundles ORDER BY name ASC;
```

This query returns the following order:

```
Package 1
Package 10
Package 11
Package 2
Package 3
etc...
```

Is there anyway with mysql to make it order naturally:

```
Package 1
Package 2
Package 3
...
Package 10
```

or is this something i will have to code manually with the results.

I have tried:

```
ORDER BY ABS(name)
and
ORDER BY (name+0)
```

on suggestions found around the web, neither work.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153633/natural-sort-in-mysql