# How do you sort fields which have numbers in a mathematical order

Tags: mysql, natural-sort

The following users are present in our database..

```
create table users (id, name);

name [u1, u2, u3, u4, u5, u6, u7, u8, u9, u10, u11, ...]
```

If the above field is sorted in an ascending fashion, the output is as follows..

```
u1, u10, u11, u2, u3, u4 ...
```

Is it possible to sort this in the order at the top (i.e. list all single digits, double digits ...)

Comment: uel - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153633/natural-sort-in-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTR(name FROM 2) AS UNSIGNED)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
SELECT name
FROM users
ORDER BY LENGTH(name), name
```