# MySql natural sorting with offset from a certain value

Tags: mysql, offset, natural-sort

I have the data:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sort` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `sort` (`id`, `value`) VALUES
    (1, 'abc2'),
    (2, 'abc20'),
    (3, 'abc1'),
    (4, 'abc10'),
    (5, 'abc3');
```

I want to have all the rows starting from a specified id then to the end of that result set to be added all the rows until that specified id and all sorted by value.

So i come out with this:

```
SET @id=3;
SELECT * FROM sort
ORDER BY 
id=@id DESC, value>=(SELECT value FROM sort WHERE id=@id) DESC, value ASC;
```

Everything works fine but is not a natural sort. With the query above i get the result `abc1, abc10, abc2, abc20, abc3`. The result I'm looking for is `abc1, abc2, abc3, abc10, abc20`. And of course if I change @id=4 the results should be `abc10, abc20, abc1, abc2, abc3`.

With the query bellow I get the natural sorting I want.

```
SELECT * FROM sort ORDER BY LENGTH(value), value;
```

So the question is: **How can I combine the two ORDER BY clauses into one?**

Comment: define "natural sorting", what is the expected result

Comment: This is a "natural sorting": "-10, -2.11, -2.10, -1, 0, abc1, abc001, abc2, abc10". If you run both SELECT query the result from the first is a natural sorting and the second is not. I am quite happy with the result from the first SELECT query so I just want to combine the two SELECT query into the second one.

Comment: How about ab10 and abc2?

Comment: Have a look at: [Natural Sort in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153633/natural-sort-in-mysql)

Comment: I don't care of that much of a detail. Probably the rigth order will  by ab10, abc2

Comment: I've read that but my biggest problem is to combine the two SELECT query into the last one, the two ORDER BY clauses into the last SELECT query.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sort 
ORDER BY  
    id=@id DESC,
    LENGTH(value),
    value>=(SELECT value FROM sort WHERE id=@id) DESC, 
    value ASC;`
```

Comment: Does not work. The results should be: if(id==1){abc2, abc3, abc10, abc20, abc1} if(id==2){abc20, abc1, abc2, abc3, abc10} if(id==3){abc3, abc10, abc20, abc1, abc2} if(id==4){abc10, abc20, abc1, abc2, abc3} if(id==5){abc3, abc10, abc20, abc1, abc2}