# Order by mixed alpha-numeric column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have the following values in my rows (they should be ordered like this);

```
**CLASS_CODE**
6A
6B
6C
10A
10B
10C
```

Well if I do a simple `ORDER BY CLASS_CODE`, I will get first 10x then 6x values.

So I use `ORDER BY (CLASS_CODE+0)`, this orders them correctly so that 6x comes first, but it does not order them accordingly to chars as well.

What would be the correct way to order by, so I can get the correct order as shown above?

Comment: because MySQL will do only a string comparision 1 is before 6. What you want is a natural sort (like in PHP i.e. for arrays). I don't know if that is possible in MySQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you only use a single letter at the end of the field values, then you can use the following:

```
ORDER BY (class_code+0), right(class_code, 1)
```

Comment: I only have one letter at the end. Thank you for your solution.

Comment: The example by the OP indeed leads to assume that there's always one character after a number, but in general that may not be true. And even if it is, you still don't have to extract the rightmost character. Once you've got the order by `(class_code+0)`, the subgroups can be ordered simply by `class_code`.

Answer (score 3):

There is something here : http://www.carlos-roque.com/2011/04/19/sorting-characters-and-numbers-in-mysql/

I can't test it right now, but I believe something like that can be a nice hack :

```
SELECT CLASS_CODE as hack ... ORDER BY (CLASS_CODE+0)ASC, hack ASC
```

Maybe try to turn it around.

If that's a fail, here is some discussion about sorting in a natural fashion : [Natural Sort in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153633/natural-sort-in-mysql)

Comment: No need to alias `CLASS_CODE`, I'm sure `ORDER BY (CLASS_CODE+0)ASC, CLASS_CODE ASC` would do just as well.

Comment: I see, thought it would not be considered twice. You must be right.

Comment: Your basic idea is still correct. I can agree both with your answer and with @a'r's.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply. But it may help someone.

You have to implement Natural Sorting. To sort it using PHP, you can use `natsort()` function.

You can achieve natural sorting through MySQL also which is simple enough. For ex:

```
ORDER BY LENGTH(class_code), class_code
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had this scenario and I use the CAST function. In this case `ORDER BY CAST(class_code AS DECIMAL)`