# MySQL ordering is lying to me

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Right, this is a very odd issue that I'm wondering how i am going to explain it succinctly.

I have a WP plugin that records rows in a mysql table like so:

```
meta_id    post_id    meta_key    meta_value 
65387      605        _likes      9
```

Then on one of my pages I was running a query to select the most liked posts, ie. ORDER by meta_value DESC. Now i noticed on my site that whenever a post reached 10 it would not appear as top anymore and disappear from the query results. Odd.

I went to the database and (in PHPMyAdmin) ordered by meta_value and it did return 9 as the top results, none of the 10's appeared!?

One thing I thought it might be is the type of field (meta_value), these are the settings:

```
#   Column      Type        Collation           Attributes  Null    Default
4   meta_value  longtext    latin1_swedish_ci               Yes     NULL
```

Can anyone think of anything that might mean the ORDER BY is not working when the value is 10 or above!?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't change column datatype don't worry ... No need to do that

you need to just  `cast` it's values in integers in `ORDER BY`  clause.

user trick :

```
ORDER BY meta_value+0;
```

OR

```
ORDER BY CAST(meta_value as SIGNED);
```

Answer (score 1):

Text fields don't order like number fields do. 9 is a higher value than 10 when descending (In text terms) as 10 starts with 1, and it's the 1 that it's working off, not the whole number, so 9 appears before 10.

Comment: Ohhhh. Ok. Because WordPress uses this field for multiple meta_value's i cant really change the type, is there anything I can do?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557172/mysql-order-by-sorting-alphanumeric-correctly