# Output list by numeric-alphabetic order - MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a list of codes:

```
1A
1B
1C
2A
2B
2C
.....
10A
10B..
11A
11B..
...
```

But when I sort I get the below order (I have removed some values from the list to make it shorter)

```
10A
10A
10B
10B
11A
11A
1A
1A
1B
1B
1C
2B
2B
2B
2B
2C
```

How do I order the list by the numeric value and the alphabet in the proper order (asc)?

Comment: see related http://stackoverflow.com/a/8557307/908471

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL 'Order By' - sorting alphanumeric correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557172/mysql-order-by-sorting-alphanumeric-correctly)

Answer (score 2):

I didn't know that it was possible do do something like this, but it looks like it is:

```
SELECT code
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY Convert(code, unsigned), code
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql doesn't directly support "natural" sorting like that, but you can fake it up with a more complicated order by clause. However, since mysql doesn't have capturing regexes that'd let you find where the numeric/alpha split in those strings is, it'd be hideously ugly to write one that can appropriately split things up so you could do

```
SELECT ugly_split_function1(yourfield) AS alpha, ugly_splitfunction2(yourfield) AS numeric
....
ORDER BY numeric, alpha
```

The best solution would be to split up that field into two separate ones, so you can directly sort on the individual fields.

Comment: Make sure you convert `numeric` to an integer type, or it will still sort funky. You can also just do `SELECT yourfield` and move the splits into the `SORT` clause so you don't have to look at the ugliness in the result.

Answer (score 0):

IF your codes are ALWAYS a number followed by ONLY 1 letter, the following should work...

```
 SELECT code FROM table ORDER BY LENGTH(code), code
```

Comment: Please note that the above will break if you have a changing number of letters that come after the number in your codes.