# Mysql Order By String that contains numbers stuck to letters

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have some values in a mysql database, which when using ORDER BY ASC they are displayed like this

```
178mm Diamond Core Drill
187mm Diamond Core Drill
22mm Diamond Core Drill
28mm Diamond Core Drill
32mm Diamond Core Drill
```

This is due to the ordering of the very first digit. When really it should be like this

```
22mm Diamond Core Drill
28mm Diamond Core Drill
32mm Diamond Core Drill
178mm Diamond Core Drill
187mm Diamond Core Drill
```

Is there any way to order the field by just the first full number in the string, eg 22, 28, 32 etc...

Cheers.

Comment: You can use ORDER BY column+0, but consider normalising you data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL 'Order By' - sorting alphanumeric correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557172/mysql-order-by-sorting-alphanumeric-correctly)

Answer (score 0):

The `ORDER BY column+0` as suggested in comment by @Strawberry works.

But as of myself, I prefer explicit `CAST` for code self-documentation (this will prevent future "optimization" of your code by someone deleting that "pointless" +0 ;):

```
mysql> SELECT c,CAST(c AS DECIMAL),c+0 from T order by CAST(c AS DECIMAL) ASC;
+--------------------------+--------------------+------+
| c                        | CAST(c AS DECIMAL) | c+0  |
+--------------------------+--------------------+------+
| 22mm Diamond Core Drill  |                 22 |   22 |
| 28mm Diamond Core Drill  |                 28 |   28 |
| 32mm Diamond Core Drill  |                 32 |   32 |
| 178mm Diamond Core Drill |                178 |  178 |
| 187mm Diamond Core Drill |                187 |  187 |
+--------------------------+--------------------+------+
5 rows in set, 15 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

Please note this will produce *warnings* `1292 "Truncated incorrect ... value` !

Answer (score 0):

Assuming column is called product_name (column size 100) and table is called products. How about

```
SELECT product_name FROM products ORDER BY LPAD(TRIM(product_name),100,'0') ASC ?
```