# Order By Name not working as intended - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have the following simple query:

`SELECT * FROM grade order by GRADENAME`

It outputs:

[image]

This is a problem mostly on the user experience part, Since he received the grades on the `<select></select>` element as the list above shows. Is there a way I can order them to show starting from `1A` all the way to `11D`? Is there a possible way to do it?

### EDIT

Applying `SELECT * FROM grade order by BIN(GRADENAME);`

results in:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM grade order by BIN(GRADENAME);
```

Comment: Works only for the first 4 rows. Then it starts ordering them in a weird way. What does that do exactly?

Comment: Check reference link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557172/mysql-order-by-sorting-alphanumeric-correctly

Comment: May be this link is solved your issue http://bytes.com/topic/mysql/answers/881790-mysql-natural-sort

Answer (score 1):

May be something like this

```
SELECT * FROM grade 
Order By Cast(SubString(GRADENAME,1,Length(GRADENAME) -1 As Int),Right(GRADENAME,1)
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM grade 
Order By lpad(GRADENAME, 10, 0)
```

Comment: This does work as well. But it has more code than `SELECT * FROM grade order by lpad(GRADENAME, 10, 0)`. I will stay with the one I found. Thanks for your answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT GRADEID, 
       GRADENAME 
FROM   GRADE 
GROUP  BY GRADENAME 
ORDER  BY 2;
```