# Laravel/ PHP: Order By Alphabetical with numbers in order

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

When ordering things by Alphabetical Order, I'm left with this:

```
S1 Episode 1
S1 Episode 11
S1 Episode 12
S1 Episode 2
S1 Episode 3

S2 Episode 1
S2 Episode 11
```

**Example Code:**

```
DB::table('test')->orderby('title', 'ASC')->get();
```

Etc. I need these to be ordered properly. Any solutions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are being posed with the problem of sorting items alphanumerically, or in computer science terms, **natural sorting.**

There are [many ways to achieve a natural sort with straight MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8557307/1188035) but you could also take the results from your Laravel helper into array format and implement PHP's [`natsort` function instead](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php).

From the methods I found above, I derived the best way that would likely solve your problem with the example code:

```
DB::table('test')->orderBy('LENGTH(title)', 'ASC')
    ->orderBy('title', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

however I'm not sure if the helper will complain about receiving a MySQL function instead of a straight column name into the `orderBy` function. I'm only transcribing from the references I used in combination with your example too - I cannot guarantee the efficacy.

Comment: Worked for me but I had to use orderByRaw(LENGTH(field),'ASC'). Thanks a lot, very intuitive solution.

Answer (score 10):

It might be late but for others it might help.

Based on above link I found below, I derived the best way that would likely solve your problem with the example code:
https://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-order-string-as-int/

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM <table> ORDER BY CAST(<column> AS unsigned)
```

**Example for laravel**

```
DB::table('test')
    ->orderByRaw("CAST(title as UNSIGNED) ASC")
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 5):

For Laravel this also works:

```
$collection = $collection->sortBy('order', SORT_REGULAR, true);
```

Comment: Note that SORT_REGULAR is a PHP constant, not a Laravel directive.  Here is the PHP reference, plus other constants for sorting, such as SORT_NATURAL, SORT_NUMERIC, etc: https://www.php.net/manual/en/array.constants.php

Answer (score 4):

```
DB::table('test')->orderByRaw('LENGTH(title)', 'ASC')
->orderBy('title', 'ASC')
->get();
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.

Comment: you are ingenious!

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel Collection:

```
$collection = collect([
    ['sn' => '2'],
    ['sn' => 'B'],
    ['sn' => '1'],
    ['sn' => '10'],
    ['sn' => 'A'],
    ['sn' => '13'],
]);
```

`$sorted = $collection->sortBy('sn');`

```
//print_r($collection);

Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [sn] => 1
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sn] => 2
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [sn] => 10
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [sn] => 13
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [sn] => A
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [sn] => B
                )

        )

)
```

As you can see, this will sort it correctly. However, if you want to sort it and reindex it then,

`$sorted = $collection->sortBy('sn')->values()->all();`

```
//print_r($sorted)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sn] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sn] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [sn] => 10
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [sn] => 13
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [sn] => A
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [sn] => B
        )

)
```

Furthermore, You can also pass your own callback to determine how to sort the collection values.

```
$sorted = $collection->sortBy(function ($item, $key) {
    //your logic
});
```

For more details: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-sortby

Answer (score 0):

Basically like the accepted answer but with the comma removed and orderByRaw.  Otherwise I get an error about bindings

`DB::table('test')->orderByRaw('LENGTH(title) ASC') ->orderBy('title', 'ASC') ->get();`

Comment: Hi would someone please confirm what is wrong with the above? (just so I don't make the same mistake again) Thanks

Comment: not sure looks good to me

Answer (score -1):

Order the resulting collection

```
$unorderedThings = Thing::orderBy('id')->get();
$orderedThings=$unorderedThings->sort();
```

Answer (score -1):

This work's for me using **eloquent**, is very simple:

**Eloquent**:

```
$tests = Test::all();
$tests = $tests->sortBy('title', SORT_REGULAR, false); // false=ascending, true=descending
```

**Sort numbers as text in Laravel.**

I hope this is very helpful