# Natural sorting of related Models in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-relations

I have a Laravel project set up which uses vueJs as the frontend and there I need to sort related models naturally. So:

I have a **Project model** which has a **hasMany** relationship to a **Plannings model**.
I am displaying all plannings on the show page of the project. And I need to sort the plannings on that page naturally by title.

At the moment my code looks like this (I found the sorting solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58796926/11792214)):

**ProjectController:**

```
public function show(Project $project)
    {
        if (auth()->user()->id == $project->user_id || auth()->user()->hasPermissionTo('edit_users')) {
            return New ProjectResource($project->load(['plannings' => function ($query) {
                                                $query->orderByRaw('LENGTH(title)', 'ASC')
                                                    ->orderBy('title', 'ASC');
                                                }]));
        } else {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Kein Zugriff'], 403);
        }

    }
```

**ProjectResource:**

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->title,
            'user_id' => $this->user_id,
            'plannings' => PlanningResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('plannings')),
        ];
    }
```

**This works for example titles like this:**
(the array is already in the order of the result of the sorting)

```
$plannings = [
  'Project #1',
  'Project #2',
  'Project #10', 
  'Project #11', 
  'Project Room 1 #1', 
  'Project Room 1 #2', 
  'Project Room 1 #11'
];
```

**However it does not work for example titles like those:**
(the array is already in the order of the result of the sorting)

```
$plannings = [
  'Gang 7 - 8m x 2m LPH 2,5m 300LUX',
  'Gang 8 - 5m x 2m LPH 2,5m 300LUX',
  'Gang 1 - 13m x 2m LPH 2,5m 300LUX',
  'Gang 3 - 13m x 2m LPH 2,5m 300LUX',
  'Gang 4 - 19m x 2m LPH 2,5m 300LUX',
  'Gang 5 - 17m x 2m LPH 2,5m 300LUX',
  'Gang 6 - 19m x 2m LPH 2,5m 300LUX',
  'Gang 2 - 13m x 2m LPH 2,5m 300LUX #2'
];
```

So I was thinking, maybe I can use the collection method `sortBy('key', SORT_NATURAL, true)`?

However, I do not know how I would implement that in my `ProjectController` or `ProjectResource`. Does someone know a solution to this?

Comment: How does it not work? for performance i would always sort in the database

Comment: The second array should have the order:
Gang 1 - ...
Gang 2 - ...
Gang 3 - ... 
and so on.

Comment: But you are sorting on length? then title? added my answer guess the problem is the order

Comment: I guess my problem is not that it does not work as it is supposed to work based on my code, but more that I do not know how I can achieve the right sorting that is not dependent on the length of the string. It simply should sort alphbetically/naturally

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36716875/2943403