# Alfanumeric ordering

Tags: mysql

I want to sort the following data items but sometimes he put the B for an A.  (U8B-U8A, U11B-U11A, U15B-U15A and U17B-U17A) 
The query that is use is :

```
SELECT * FROM trainers
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTR(cat,2) AS SIGNED) AS
```

How can a solve this problem?

```
Cat  fisrt    last
U5   Steve    Vangeel
U6   Steve    Vangeel
U7A  Davy     Cums
U7B  Gerbe    Suttels
U8B  Roel     Tastenoye
U8A  Davy     Vlasselaerts
U9A  Jordi    Knops
U9B  Piet     Veulemans
U9C  Tom      Delie
U9C  Patrick  Uyttebroeck
U10A Jonas    Delvaux
U10B Ruben    Francois
U11B Peter    Desmet
U11A Tom      Delie
U12B Hans     Smets
U12A Joeri    Tits
U13  Patrick  Vanuytrecht
U15B Ronny    Vanderhoeft
U15A Gunther  Roosen
U17B Dirk     Knops
U17A Jonas    Vanhelmont
U17A Tim      Knops
U21A Patrick  Uyttebroeck
U21B Luc      Mathues
```

Comment: How do you want to sort the data items?  Why doesn't your code work?

Comment: Try this `ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTR(cat,2) AS SIGNED), SUBSTR(cat,2)`

Comment: same question is answered here [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557172/mysql-order-by-sorting-alphanumeric-correctly