# Java sorting is not the same with MySQL sorting

Tags: java, mysql, sorting, collections, comparator

I need to check the sorting in the table and table content is given by MySQL. I'm trying the following:
`Collections.sort(sorted, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);`

And get the following result:
`tes3@test.com` 
`test4@test.com` 
`test5@test.com`
`test@test.com` 
`test_user@mail.com`
`user-og@driver.com`

And this is what I get from MySQL by query:
`SELECT 'email' FROM 'user' WHERE 1 ORDER BY 'user'.'email' ASC`  :

`tes3@test.com` 
`test_user@mail.com` 
`test@test.com` 
`test4@test.com` 
`test5@test.com`
`user-og@driver.com`

Seems like Java sorts according to ASCII table:
http://www.asciitable.com/
`4 (52) - @ (64) - _ (95)`

But in MySQL result the order is  `_ -> @ -> 4`

The `email` field collation is: `utf8_unicode_ci`
What is the problem and is there any comparator to make ordering in the same way?

Comment: AFAIK java handels the `_` different then they are getting handelt in sql when you are sorting. But the cause of this could be your local language setting.

Comment: how did you do it inside ur code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL 'Order By' - sorting alphanumeric correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557172/mysql-order-by-sorting-alphanumeric-correctly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Collator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html):

> The Collator class performs locale-sensitive String comparison. You use this class to build searching and sorting routines for natural language text.

And code will be:

```
Collator coll = Collator.getInstance(Locale.US);
coll.setStrength(Collator.IDENTICAL); 
Collections.sort(words, coll);
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped with symbols like digits and "@", but now I have problems with `space` recognizing. MySQL output: 
`Existing_test_company` `Test company` `Test company 10` `test_` `test_1`

Java sorting result using Collator: 
`Existing_test_company` `test_` `test_1` `Test company` `Test company`

Comment: Solved by adding a rule: `String rules = ((RuleBasedCollator) Collator.getInstance(Locale.US)).getRules();
RuleBasedCollator correctedCollator 
    = new RuleBasedCollator(rules.replaceAll("<'\u005f'", "<' '<'\u005f'"));`