# Java Collator with similar characteristic as MySQLs utf8_general_ci collation

Tags: java, mysql, utf-8, collation

Is there any `Collator` implementation which has the same characteristics as MySQL's utf8_general_ci? I need a collator which is case insensitive and *does not distinguish* german umlauts like `ä` with the vowel `a`.

Background:
We recently encountered a bug which was caused by a wrong collation in our table. The used collation was `utf8_general_ci` where `utf8_bin` would be the correct one. The particular column had a unique index. The `utf8_general_ci` collation does not distinguish between words like `pöker` and `poker`, so the rows were merged, which was not desired.
I now need a way to implement a module for our Java application, which repairs the wrong rows.

Comment: change the collation of particular column(unique index column) to `utf8_bin`

Comment: We already did that. The remaining problem is repairing the existing rows. The application needs to rebuild those faulty rows using the raw data.

Comment: If you want case folding, but accent sensitivity, please file a request at http://bugs.mysql.com .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following collator:

```
Collator collator = Collator.getInstance();
collator.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
```

A collator with this strength will only consider primary differences significant during comparison.

Consider an example:

```
System.out.println(compare("abc", "ÀBC", Collator.PRIMARY)); //base char
System.out.println(compare("abc", "ÀBC", Collator.SECONDARY)); //base char + accent
System.out.println(compare("abc", "ÀBC", Collator.TERTIARY)); //base char + accent + case
System.out.println(compare("abc", "ÀBC", Collator.IDENTICAL)); //base char + accent + case + bits

private static int compare(String first, String second, int strength) {
   Collator collator = Collator.getInstance();
   collator.setStrength(strength);
   return collator.compare(first, second);
}
```

The output is:

```
0
-1
-1
-1
```

Have a look at these links for more information:

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=207
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html#PRIMARY

Comment: Note that by using `Collator.getInstance();` you are leaving it to circumstances what collator you actually get... I recommend choosing and explicitly specifying a `Locale`... The question then becomes... what locale? As it stands this code will pick a French or German locale if the computer it's running on is set to those settings... Might be fine, or might require your user to change their Windows settings just to get the correct result in your program...

Comment: Also see this blog post: [Using MySQL Collations in Java](http://techblog.molindo.at/2009/10/using-mysql-collations-in-java.html)

Comment: Also see this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33999947/java-sorting-is-not-the-same-with-mysql-sorting

Comment: This doesn't work for all Unicode strings.  For example, with upper and lowercase strings using the Cyrillic alphabet, `compare("АВС", "авс", Collator.PRIMARY)` returns `-1`, regardless of the strength setting (although `String.equalsIgnoreCase` returns `true`).  Therefore, this approach *does not* correspond to MySQL's "utf8_general_ci" collation, which is what the question is asking.  Unfortunately, I don't think there is any clean way to use `java.text.Collator` to precisely emulate "utf8_general_ci" without knowing which `Locale` to use for a particular set of strings.