# MySQL - sort text column

Tags: mysql

I have table:

```
id (int) | floor (text)
-----------------------
1        | 1
2        | 10
3        | 7
4        | Ground floor
```

I want the result from my query to sort the data on the text column `floor`. Is possible to get result like that?

```
id (int) | floor (text)
-----------------------
4        | Ground floor
1        | 1
3        | 7
2        | 10
```

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557172/mysql-order-by-sorting-alphanumeric-correctly

Comment: What sql statements you have tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way you can do it using mysql's silent conversion technique and then applying it to order by clause

```
select * from mytable
order by 
case 
 when `floor`+0 = 0 then 0 
   else 1
 end , `floor`+0,`floor`
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/119d2/2

Or even more easy

```
select * from mytable
order by `floor`+0,`floor`
```