# Order MySQL result

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm using MySQL/MariaDB. I have an query where I use `ORDER BY user_id ASC` it gives me the following result:

```
+---------+
| user_id |
+---------+
| admin1  |
| admin10 |
| admin11 |
| admin2  |
| user1   |
| user10  |
| user11  |
| user12  |
| user13  |
| user2   |
| user20  |
| user21  |
| user22  |
| user23  |
+---------+
```

I tried the suggested solution `ORDER BY LENGTH(user_id), user_id ASC` that works great as long as all `user_id`'s starts with `user`. But if I have `user_id`'s that start with let's say `admin` then it gives me this:

```
+---------+
| user_id |
+---------+
| user1   |
| user2   |
| admin1  |
| admin2  |
| user10  |
| user11  |
| user12  |
| user13  |
| user20  |
| user21  |
| user22  |
| user23  |
| admin10 |
| admin11 |
+---------+
```

But I would like the result to order like this:

```
+---------+
| user_id |
+---------+
| admin1  |
| admin2  |
| admin10 |
| admin11 |
| user1   |
| user2   |
| user10  |
| user11  |
| user12  |
| user13  |
| user20  |
| user21  |
| user22  |
| user23  |
+---------+
```

Can I achieve this with SQL?

Comment: Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557172/mysql-order-by-sorting-alphanumeric-correctly)

Answer (score 5):

Use the `LENGTH` function as well as your column

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY LENGTH(user_id), user_id ASC
```

Output

```
user_id
user1
user2
user10
user11
user12
user13
user20
user21
user22
user23
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23f4de/3/0

Comment: Sorry I realised that I have `user_id`'s that start with `admin` also. I've updated the question and the SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01eef0/1/0

Answer (score 0):

Are the ids *always* `REGEXP '^[[:alpha:]]+[[:digit:]]+$`?  If so, then use `REGEXP_REPLACE` to remove the digits to sort by the alpha part, then remove the letters and add 0 (to turn into a number) to sort the numeric part.  Something like:

```
ORDER BY REGEXP_REPLACE(user_id, '[[:digit:]]+$', ''),
         REGEXP_REPLACE(user_id, '^[[:alpha:]]+', '') + 0
```

Another idea:

```
ORDER BY REGEXP_REPLACE(user_id,
              '([[:digit:]]+)',
              RIGHT(CONCAT('0000000', '\\1'), 8))
```

The principle is to put enough leading zeros on the numeric part so that a string compare will work "correctly".

Note:  This uses feature(s) of MariaDB that are not available in MySQL.