# MySql values do not arranged by proper value

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a Mysql table,
I want to sort the values in the table by size of the `meta_value` from biggest to smallest.

Look at the order of the value? 
How come `150,000,000` is smaller than `1,555,555` .

[image]

Comment: The left-alignment indicates that `meta_value` is a char field, not a number, so you're getting alphabetical sorting, which doesn't care if the value happens to represent a number. So, at the 3rd character, `0` gets sorted before `5`, and the rest is history. So, likely duplicate of [MySQL 'Order By' - sorting alphanumeric correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557172/mysql-order-by-sorting-alphanumeric-correctly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meta_value is a CHAR column, not a number column. If your meta value comes from another data source then you will need to use natural sorting, and you can use `ORDER BY LENGTH(alphanumeric), alphanumeric`

If you have control over the content in meta_value you could consider modifying the column data type to int or numeric or some other numeric data type. Then you would get the sort you expect.  However, changing a data type with existing data runs the risk of encountering non-standard data, so you need to know exactly what values are in that column.