# I cant sort max query of varchar

Tags: mysql

I have id table primary key using varchar (BG-1) , I check max of id to decide what next id, but when data reach BG-10, the table cant add more data, because my query read BG-9 as max not BG-10, how to fix it??

Comment: Possible dublicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557172/mysql-order-by-sorting-alphanumeric-correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your primary key is a column named "id" you could cast the number part as an integer and eliminate the "BG-" part, like this:

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTR(id,4) AS UNSIGNED)) FROM table
```

Comment: thank, work perfectly