# Sorting Column alphabetically with numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, psql

I have table with column `:name`. 
I want ordering `:name` alphabetically.

Use `Item.order(:name)` and get `"item 14", "item 15", "item 16", "item 3", "item 4"`. But I want `"item 3", "item 4", "item 14", "item 15", "item 16"`

How to achieve this?

Comment: Will the names _always_ have the same format (i.e. string, space, number)?

Comment: No, it's only example. razvans gave good link. It helped me

Comment: Great, thanks for clarifying. In that case, +1 to @razvans :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @razvans for the direction of the search.
I found solution [enter link description here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/52626)

I have:

```
 id |   name   
----+----------
  2 | item 2
  3 | item 12 
  1 | item 3
  4 | item 17
  5 | df38
  6 | aaa
  7 | a13v
  8 | a13a
  9 | item 00
(9 rows)
```

And with this code:

```
select name from table_name order by left(name, 1), substring(name, '\d+')::int NULLS FIRST, name;
```

I got:

```
   name   
----------
 aaa
 a13a
 a13v
 df38
 item 00
 item 2
 item 3
 item 12 
 item 17
(9 rows)
```

This solution is on ruby on rails:

```
Item.order("left(name, 1), substring(name, '\\d+')::int NULLS FIRST, name").pluck(:name)
```

That's what I need!

Answer (score 6):

This seems to work

```
Item.order("LENGTH(name)", :name).pluck(:name)
```

You can check this out: [MySQL 'Order By' - sorting alphanumeric correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557172/mysql-order-by-sorting-alphanumeric-correctly)

Comment: Thanks, this helped solve a bug for our ordering. We needed this to order storage unit numbers. You can think of the units being numerically ordered, with the possibility of a letter in front as a prefix, e.g A1, A2...A10, A11

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
Item.order('CAST(name AS DECIMAL) ASC')
```

Just a guess, but could work... good luck!

Comment: This actually did what I was looking to do! (sort by alphabetical, then numerical). I was able to do: `order('CAST(brand AS DECIMAL) ASC').order('name ASC')` - so thank you very much for this!