# mysql sort by number and then varchar

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

I want to sort data like below in mysql

**unsorted data**

aa
1
2
f
11
3
df
10

**Sorted data(desired output)**

1
2
3
10
11
aa
df
f

Comment: A simple ORDER BY will fetch you the desired result
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html

Comment: So you have the same column containing numbers and characters?

Comment: is each number  / string in a row or is "aa 1 2 f 11 3 df 10" a string ? pls show your table structure

Comment: @Wilson: you are wong because it would return the data as `1 10 11 2 3 aa df f` and not as the desired output.

What is needed here is called `natural sort`. As far as i know MySQL doesn't provide any build-in solution for this. There are a lot of ways with that you can do it but you need to work with a few tricks. You might look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557172/mysql-order-by-sorting-alphanumeric-correctly).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL 'Order By' - sorting alphanumeric correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557172/mysql-order-by-sorting-alphanumeric-correctly)

Comment: So you have the same column containing numbers and characters? – davidbaumann
Yes