# I need to sort digits by the smallest to biggest in mathematical way

Tags: php, mysql

i have such a sql query:

`SQL:`

```
SELECT *
FROM statistic_table
ORDER BY lot_oldness_sum,
         lot_oldness_sum2 ASC
```

and I'm getting result

212
22
224
225

I need to get by smallest digit to biggest in such a way: 22 212 224 225

I've also made the another query:

`SQL:`

```
SELECT *
FROM statistic_table
ORDER BY MAX(lot_oldness_sum),
         MAX(lot_oldness_sum2) ASC
```

but still the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557172/mysql-order-by-sorting-alphanumeric-correctly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL 'Order By' - sorting alphanumeric correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557172/mysql-order-by-sorting-alphanumeric-correctly)

Comment: And if it’s always numeric data then store it as numeric and not as text in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM statistic_table ORDER BY LENGTH(lot_oldness_sum), lot_oldness_sum ASC"
```

This one worked for me.