# How to sort alphanumeric text in a query?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a field which I'm using as a row source for a listbox.
The field holds values which look like: A1, A2, A10, AB, 1, 2.
I want it to look like: 1, 2, A1, A2, A10, AB.

I tried:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT TenancyCode FROM tbl1 WHERE 
TenancyCode IS NOT NULL ORDER BY TenancyCode 
ASC"
```

The result is not as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some fancy string handling to split the two parts.

Then, first sort on the alpha part (as text), next the numeric part (as a number):

```vb
"SELECT 
    TenancyCode 
FROM 
    tbl1 
GROUP BY
    TenancyCode
HAVING 
    TenancyCode IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY 
    Mid([TenancyCode], 1, Len([TenancyCode]) - Len(Str(Val('1' & StrReverse(Nz([TenancyCode]))))) + 2) ASC,
    Val(StrReverse(Mid(Str(Val('1' & StrReverse(Nz([TenancyCode])))), 3))) ASC"
```

`Val` is used to strip the leading alpha part (the letters) to obtain the numeric part.

Comment: this looks promising tried exactly as you said but it doesn't sort as expected. I don't get any errors. Which makes it promising. Is it because the field also contain nulls?

Comment: You can use _Nz_ to accept _Null_. See edited answer, please. Otherwise, it will sort as your example data.

Comment: I get a conflict with DISTINCT. The code works without it but it would be good if it only shows distinct values. I know my sample code doesn't show repeated values but please accept this as a typo. Very much appreciated your help.

Comment: Then try with `Group By`. See edited answer, please.

Comment: Wao. That is good! Works as expected. You have made my day! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Use a formatted field for the sorting like this:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT TenancyCode FROM tbl1 WHERE 
TenancyCode IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Format$(Right$(TendancyCode, Len(TendencyCode) - 1), "0000") ASC"
```

That will strip off the first character and format the numeric part to 4 digits. If your data does not always begin with 1 alpha character then the solution is much more complex.

Read more about options here: [MySQL 'Order By' - sorting alphanumeric correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557172/mysql-order-by-sorting-alphanumeric-correctly)

Comment: thanks but there is a end of statement error at the `"0000"` part.

Comment: oh - try using single quotes instead of double quotes - `'` instead of `"`