# Natural sorting Ajax Datatables in Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, natural-sort

Struggling to figure out how to set natural sorting in AJAX Datatables using Codeigniter Active record.
The field that should be sorted has, in most cases, just digits...in other cases a string, so the MySQL table field is set as VARCHAR.

I need to srt naturally the field to be displayed in Datatables.

The Active record Codeigniter query is the following.

```
function list_all($limit,$start,$col,$dir)
{   
    $this->rmi_db->select (" 
        $this->table_dev.id,
        $this->table_dev.fl,
        $this->table_dev.mm,
        $this->table_dev.batch,
        $this->table_dev.n,
        $this->table_dev.ditta,
        $this->table_dev.tipo,
        $this->table_dev.costruzione,
        $this->table_dev.motori,
        $this->table_dev.nc,
        $this->table_dev.serie,
        $this->table_dev.ca,
        $this->table_dev.consegna,
        $this->table_dev.matr_usaf AS usaf,
        $this->table_dev.matr_usn AS usn,
        $this->table_dev.matr_caf AS caf,
        $this->table_dev.matr_raf AS raf,
        $this->table_dev.codici,
        $this->table_dev.note,
        $this->table_dev.reg_civili,
        $this->table_dev.matricola_civ,
        $this->table_dev.prima_reg,
        $this->table_dev.n_contratto,
        $this->table_dev.data_contratto,
        $this->table_dev.importo_contratto,
        $this->table_dev.note_contratto,
        $this->table_dev.f29,
        $this->table_dev.f30,     
        ");
    $this->rmi_db->from("$this->table_dev");
    $this->rmi_db->where("$this->table_dev.mm !=", "");
    $this->rmi_db->limit($limit, $start);
    $this->rmi_db->order_by($col, $dir);
    $query = $this->rmi_db->get();

    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
        return $query->result(); 
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The mm field should be sorted naturally. I have no idea how and if it's possible to fix the issue.
I tried the solution in this discussion [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557172/mysql-order-by-sorting-alphanumeric-correctly), the Bin way, but the select doesn't work properly ( got 500 server error)

Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557172/mysql-order-by-sorting-alphanumeric-correctly), Try below. It should work but not tested.

```
function list_all($limit,$start,$col,$dir)
{   
$this->rmi_db->select (" 
    $this->table_dev.id,
    $this->table_dev.fl,
    $this->table_dev.mm,
    $this->table_dev.mm, CAST($this->table_dev.mm as SIGNED) AS casted_column,//changed
    $this->table_dev.batch,
    $this->table_dev.n,
    $this->table_dev.ditta,
    $this->table_dev.tipo,
    $this->table_dev.costruzione,
    $this->table_dev.motori,
    $this->table_dev.nc,
    $this->table_dev.serie,
    $this->table_dev.ca,
    $this->table_dev.consegna,
    $this->table_dev.matr_usaf AS usaf,
    $this->table_dev.matr_usn AS usn,
    $this->table_dev.matr_caf AS caf,
    $this->table_dev.matr_raf AS raf,
    $this->table_dev.codici,
    $this->table_dev.note,
    $this->table_dev.reg_civili,
    $this->table_dev.matricola_civ,
    $this->table_dev.prima_reg,
    $this->table_dev.n_contratto,
    $this->table_dev.data_contratto,
    $this->table_dev.importo_contratto,
    $this->table_dev.note_contratto,
    $this->table_dev.f29,
    $this->table_dev.f30,     
    ");
$this->rmi_db->from("$this->table_dev");
$this->rmi_db->where("$this->table_dev.mm !=", "");
$this->rmi_db->limit($limit, $start);
$this->rmi_db->order_by($col, $dir);
$this->rmi_db->order_by('casted_column', 'ASC'); // changed
$this->rmi_db->order_by($this->table_dev.mm, 'ASC'); // changed
$query = $this->rmi_db->get(); //changed

if($query->num_rows()>0)
{
    return $query->result(); 
}
else
{
    return null;
}
}
```

comment if you face any issue

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and help Aman. The suggested code didn't fix the issue...since the mm field is not exactly sorted in natural sort...it looks like a 
progression in multiples of 2. You can see the result here: https://gavs.it/rmidev

Comment: Did you changed this line from $this->db->order_by('name', 'ASC'); to $this->db->order_by('mm', 'ASC');

Comment: Yep, and the query is now ordered even if in a weird way.....maybe BIN fix provide result multiplied by 2...did you see the link above? Instead 1,2,3,4,5 and so on... I get 1,2,4,8,16,32,6,128 and so on. Again thanks for all your help.

Comment: Yes, I saw that output. Please check updated answer with Cast way !

Comment: Oh my....works perfect now Aman! Thanks a lot. I've just edited a bit the following line: CAST(name as SIGNED) AS casted_column, into CAST($this->table_dev.mm as SIGNED) AS casted_column, Can I ask what's the purpose of "as SIGNED"? I have learnt a lot thanks to your help. Many thanks

Comment: Welcome-@Federico, SIGNED - it cast mm value in signed (negative and positive numbers) for example signed byte represent -128 to 127