# ORDER BY numeric and characters

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I want to sort the following data items in the order they are presented below:

```
ZZZ-AA1
ZZZ-AA2
ZZZ-AA3
ZZZ-AA11
ZZZ-AA12
ZZZ-AAA1
ZZZ-AB1
ZZZ-AB2
ZZZ-BB1
ZZZ-BB12
ZZZ-CA1
```

Any tricks to make it sort more properly?

Thanks!

Queries that I have tried:

```
SELECT bay FROM table GROUP BY bay ORDER BY SUBSTR(bay FROM 1 FOR 6), CAST(SUBSTR(bay FROM 6) AS UNSIGNED)
SELECT bay FROM table GROUP BY bay ORDER BY LENGTH(bay), bay
```

Comment: [MySQL 'Order By' - sorting alphanumeric correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557172/mysql-order-by-sorting-alphanumeric-correctly)

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: @fadlikidd I believe it its 5.7.24

Comment: Is it safe to assume that all the next value after `-` will have at least two alphabet values before numbers?

Comment: @fadlikidd Yes, at least two alphabet only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On MySQL prior to 8.0, trying to achieve this is quite a long way. In **MySQL v8.0**, one possible solution is using [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) like:

```
SELECT * FROM test
      ORDER BY 
      REGEXP_REPLACE(val, "[0-9]", "") ASC,
      ABS(REGEXP_REPLACE(val, "[A-Za-z]", "")) ASC;
```

However, since you're using MysQL v5.7, this is what I come up with:

```
SELECT val FROM 
(SELECT val, 
     LEAST(IF(LOCATE(0, val)=0,999,LOCATE(0, val)), 
     IF(LOCATE(1, val)=0,999,LOCATE(1, val)),  
     IF(LOCATE(2, val)=0,999,LOCATE(2, val)), 
     IF(LOCATE(3, val)=0,999,LOCATE(3, val)),  
     IF(LOCATE(4, val)=0,999,LOCATE(4, val)), 
     IF(LOCATE(5, val)=0,999,LOCATE(5, val)),  
     IF(LOCATE(6, val)=0,999,LOCATE(6, val)), 
     IF(LOCATE(7, val)=0,999,LOCATE(7, val)),  
     IF(LOCATE(8, val)=0,999,LOCATE(8, val)), 
     IF(LOCATE(9, val)=0,999,LOCATE(9, val))) lv
FROM test) t
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(val,1,lv-1) ASC, SUBSTRING(val,lv)+0 ASC;
```

The idea is to get the first number occurrence then use that to separate between the values before numbers and the numbers itself using [LOCATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) function:

```
LOCATE(1, val)
*translate to "Locate the number 1 in `val` column".

IF(LOCATE(1, val)=0, 999, LOCATE(1, val))
*translate to "If you can't locate the number 1 in `val`, return 999 
 otherwise return the location of it.".
```

Since these are numbers we're looking for, it's much easier because I'll only need to locate `0 to 9` number values. Then, if `LOCATE` return `0` as result, replace it with `999`. I replace them because I'm using [LEAST](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) to return the smallest value; which is the first number occurrence:

```
LEAST(IF(LOCATE ..
```

After that, I make the query as a sub-query then uses the result from `LEAST(IF(LOCATE ..` as the centre of `SUBSTRING` in the `ORDER BY`:

```
SUBSTRING(val,1,lv-1)
*Will return the value before the first number occurrence. 
(e.g ZZZ-AA1 to ZZZ-AA OR ZZZ-AAA1 to ZZZ-AAA).

AND 

SUBSTRING(val,lv)
*Will return the value on the first number onwards. 
(e.g. ZZZ-AA1 to 1 OR ZZZ-AAA1 to 1).
```

Of course, if you want to look at the value, you can simply add the statement in `ORDER BY` to `SELECT` like :

```
SELECT val, SUBSTRING(val,1,lv-1) , SUBSTRING(val,lv)+0  FROM 
...
```

*If you notice, in the first `SUBSTRING` I've added `lv-1` because without `minus 1`, the `SUBSTRING` will return together with the first number occurrence. And the second `SUBSTRING` I added `+0` at the end because without `plus 1` the result datatype is string so the ordering will mess up.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dbc41aae4924d607086c52616e8a52cb)

Answer (score 1):

In `MySQL 5.7`, you can try using the `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function.

```
SELECT *,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(bay
    , '1', 1)
    , '2', 1)
    , '3', 1)
    , '4', 1)
    , '5', 1)
    , '6', 1)
    , '7', 1)
    , '8', 1)
    , '9', 1)
    , '0', 1) AS alpha_key
FROM t
ORDER BY alpha_key, CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(bay, alpha_key, -1) AS UNSIGNED)
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4c3653091c653f7f9fafd88a4fd52e70)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a pair of `REGEXP_SUBSTR()`:

```
ORDER BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(tmp.`code`,"[A-Za-z-]+"), CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(tmp.`code`,"[0-9]+") AS UNSIGNED)
```

Here you can see it in action:

```
SELECT tmp.`code`,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(tmp.`code`,"[A-Za-z-]+") as `key`,
       CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(tmp.`code`,"[0-9]+") AS UNSIGNED) as `sort`
  FROM (SELECT 'ZZZ-AA1' as code UNION ALL
        SELECT 'ZZZ-AA2' as code UNION ALL
        SELECT 'ZZZ-AA3' as code UNION ALL
        SELECT 'ZZZ-AA11' as code UNION ALL
        SELECT 'ZZZ-AA12' as code UNION ALL
        SELECT 'ZZZ-AAA1' as code UNION ALL
        SELECT 'ZZZ-AB1' as code UNION ALL
        SELECT 'ZZZ-AB2' as code UNION ALL
        SELECT 'ZZZ-BB1' as code UNION ALL
        SELECT 'ZZZ-BB12' as code UNION ALL
        SELECT 'ZZZ-CA1' as code) tmp
 ORDER BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(tmp.`code`,"[A-Za-z-]+"),
          CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(tmp.`code`,"[0-9]+") AS UNSIGNED);
```

This will be inefficient when sorting on large datasets, so be sure to use it only with the final subset that is returned.