# Laravel Eloquent - Order varchar (number with character) as number

Tags: laravel, sorting, eloquent, sql-order-by

I've got a column with house numbers saved as a varchar in my database.
Possible options are:

1. Number
2. Number + Character
3. Number + Multiple characters
4. Number - Number

I would like to order this column numerical. For example

```
120, 18, 198CC, 9A, 42-44, 198C, 9C, 9AC, 7B, 318, 7
```

Should become

```
7, 7B, 9A, 9AC, 9C, 18, 42-44, 120, 198C, 198CC, 318
```

When using a regular `...->orderBy('number')` the result is based on the length of the string instead of the numeric value. When using `->orderByRaw('CAST(amount AS DECIMAL)')` I'm getting an error because the characters can't be converted to a decimal.

Someone with a solution for this case?

Comment: Follow this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557172/mysql-order-by-sorting-alphanumeric-correctly

Comment: You should specify SQL that you are using