# How does SQL define "alphabetical order", precisely?

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, natural-sort

Most algorithms for alphabetical order give similar results, but there are a few edge cases, three are mentioned in [this article](https://www.editarians.com/ways-of-alphabetizing/).

For example:

- Newspapers
- News photography
- Newsprint

Is that correct order? Or does the space character come before "p"? Or after "p"?

Also:

- Article 19
- Article 2
- Article 20
- Article 21

Is that correct order? What if there's no space, like "Article2"? Where can I find the exact definition of alphabetical order, that will clarify this and all other edge cases?

Writing "Article 02" should put it in the correct place, but is there a character other than "0" that will work while being easier for customers to read? Like a punctuation mark or something? (Assuming I'm working with someone else's database and I only have data entry permissions.)

This question is covered in the PHP case fairly well by considering the differences between [`sort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) and [`natsort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php). (Click to see the relevant documentation.)

Comment: SQL doesn't. The RDBMS does, and depends on character sets and code page

Comment: And also some configuration for special cases such as nulls first/last

Comment: The order is defined in the "collation" of the `VARCHAR` column. There's a default collation for each database when this is not specified, but you can also set somethign different. What's the specific database? How exactly did you define the `VARCHAR` column?

Comment: @TheImpaler I'm not sure. Locally I use XAMPP's control panel v3.2.2 but the live environment is hosted by netfirms.com, so it uses whatever they use. I didn't even know there was more than one until now. Could they both alphabetise differently from each other?

Comment: XAMPP uses MariaDB as a database. The [MariaDB - ORDER BY Clause](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/order-by/) reads: "...When string values are compared, they are compared as if by the STRCMP function. STRCMP ignores trailing whitespace and may normalize characters and ignore case, depending on the collation in use..."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Natural Sort in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153633/natural-sort-in-mysql)

Comment: and [MySQL 'Order By' - sorting alphanumeric correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8557172/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order is defined in the "collation" of the VARCHAR column. There's a default collation when this is not specified, but you can also a different one as needed.

XAMPP uses MariaDB as a database. The [MariaDB - ORDER BY Clause](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/order-by/) reads:

> ...When string values are compared, they are compared as if by the STRCMP function. STRCMP ignores trailing whitespace and may normalize characters and ignore case, depending on the collation in use...

Answer (score 0):

This is more an end of the story than an answer, but recreating the titles was far too ugly a solution, so I had to take the time to edit the code.

So instead of:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    //do stuff
}
```

I had to

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $data[$row['product']] = $row;
    $title[$row['product']] = $row['title'];
}
array_multisort($title, SORT_ASC, SORT_NATURAL, $data);
foreach($data as $row){
    //do stuff
}
```

Note that the `//do stuff` section didn't require any editing whatsoever. It worked exactly as it did before.

I suspect that will help at least one person browsing this question.