# Sort MySQL query result by a alphanumeric field

Tags: php, mysql

I'm querying a table in a db using php. one of the fields is a column called "rank" and has data like the following:

```
none
1-bronze
2-silver
3-gold
...
10-ambassador
11-president
```

I want to be able to sort the results based on that "rank" column. any results where the field is "none" get excluded, so those don't factor in. As you can already guess, right now the results are coming back like this:

```
1-bronze
10-ambassador
11-president
2-silver
3-gold
```

Of course, I would like for it to be sorted so it is like the following:

```
1-bronze
2-silver
3-gold
...
10-ambassador
11-president
```

Right now the query is being returned as an object. I've tried different sort options like natsort, sort, array_multisort but haven't got it to work the way I'm sure it can. I would prefer keeping the results in an object form if possible. I'm passing the data on to a view in the next step. although, it's perfectly acceptable to pass the object to the view and then do the work there. so it's not an issue after all. :)

thank you for your help. i'm hoping I'm making sense.

Comment: Sounds like the number and the description should be separate columns...

Comment: So there can be more than one data point in the rank column? If so, sounds like the schema was designed inccorectly.

Comment: Ranks 1,2,3 and  bronze,silver,gold are in different field of DB  right ?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams ok then he should have a separate field.

Comment: While normalization is [arguably] "the correct" way, is there any way to get a "numeric collation" in MySQL? (Collation is in charge of text ordering, after all.)

Comment: Your correct, the data should have been split into two different fields but unfortunately it wasn't. i'm just trying to work with it the best that i can. :(

Comment: Maybe you should create a view that has them split properly and join against that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using this function to sort. I assume if you are getting an object you should convert object to array then use this

```
function arraySubSort($array, $subkey, $sort = 'asort') 
{
  foreach($array as $key => $value) 
  {
    $temp[$key] = strtolower($value[$subkey]);
  }

  $sort($temp);
  foreach($temp as $key => $value) 
  {
    $result[] = $array[$key];
  }
  return $result;
}

$data = $your_array;
$field = 'ranks';
arraySubSort($data,$field);
```

It will sort the array with the field you assign. If you are getting multiple records its a good thing to use to sort.

Answer (score 0):

Get the values in an array an sort it in PHP using natsort()

[Natsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php)

Answer (score 0):

This will work -

```
SELECT alphanumeric, integer FROM sorting_test ORDER BY LENGTH(alphanumeric), alphanumeric
```

source - [Natural Sort in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153633/natural-sort-in-mysql)