# How to ORDER BY varchar field as number?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have problem with sort/order by, not working like I need.

```
SELECT `proc` FROM `table` ORDER BY `proc` DESC;
```

Result:

```
80.0 proc
70.0 proc
60.0 proc
50.0 proc
40.0 proc
200.0 proc
20.0 proc
190.0 proc
180.0 proc
170.0 proc
160.0 proc
150.0 proc
140.0 proc
130.0 proc
120.0 proc
110.0 proc
100.0 proc
```

What I need is:

```
200.0 proc
190.0 proc
180.0 proc
170.0 proc
160.0 proc
150.0 proc
140.0 proc
130.0 proc
120.0 proc
110.0 proc
100.0 proc
90.0 proc
80.0 proc
70.0 proc
60.0 proc
50.0 proc
40.0 proc
20.0 proc
```

How to do it ?

Comment: Sounds like you're using `varchar` instead of `decimal`.

Comment: Is the actual text `80.0 proc` in the column?

Comment: yes varchar, yes column contain text: 80.0 proc, etc.

Comment: Why do they all contain the text `proc`? Even the column is named `proc`? [I dont get it](http://www.visualphotos.com/photo/2x4566654/businessman_jumping_out_of_window_18bsp0042rf.jpg)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Natural Sort in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153633/natural-sort-in-mysql) - if that doesn't work, look at all the questions linked to it.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It looks like "proc" is a string (`varchar` field), so it gets ordered lexically. If it is so, you can probably order it by

```
SELECT `proc` FROM `table` ORDER BY convert(`proc`, decimal) DESC;
```

Please note that such queries will be very slow, and for any serious usage it's better to use numeric columns for storing numeric data.

Comment: I would not have expected that to work but [it does](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9c9d/4)

Comment: Interesting, would have thought converting '80.0 proc' to decimal would fail.  Anyone know why?

Comment: @Bort: Could not find any specification of this [in the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html), so I'd simply guess they chose to be a bit more lenient instead of returning NULL, which is probably the only way to fail in these functions.

Comment: @Bort: in my testing, it's as if the function reads through the string up to the first "invalid" character, up to the point where the string can no longer be converted to decimal. It does the conversion on the part that can be converted. And fair warning, it considers a "comma" to be an invalid character, `CONVERT('123,456.78',DECIMAL)` will return `123`.

Comment: Had a similar issue where originally the field to order by was alpha, e.g. Math, Science, Zoology. Then it was decided the categories didn’t work for some of the items, so things were grouped into Levels, e.g. Level 1, Level 2. Then they decided that for one app, they’d just number everything. So in half the database rows the field is a varchar and in half it is really an integer. The conversion I used was ORDER BY CONVERT(`group`, UNSIGNED) WHERE `app` = 'App1'

Comment: Thanks for this, I am dealing with some legacy code using a 900 line long method to generate charts and had to convert my int to a varchar for the charts to interprate it correctly, but then anything over 10 values and it would order it incorrectly.  Now in the same query i Convert to trick the charts into displaying correctly, then Convert when I ORDER BY to get it to display in order no matter the number.  Thanks!!

Comment: this saves me . thank you

Answer (score 11):

The column field for proc is a VARCHAR or CHAR and it's treating it as a literal string--sorting alphabetically.

Convert the column to double or float or cast the value

```
SELECT `proc` FROM `table` ORDER BY CAST(`proc` AS decimal) DESC;
```

Comment: nice, but I can't change it, need a solution.

Comment: Doubles or floats can't hold alphanumeric values like "100.0 proc".

Comment: Yes, if at all possible, the column should be changed appropriately (and the fact that `'proc'` appears in every row is a concern).  However, depending on what's actually being stored, floating-point types are not the correct choice - I may have recommended either an integer type (if the decimal places did not matter) or a decimal type (if exact accuracy was required).

Comment: @Ray please check your answer in your server first then publish

Comment: It apparently works, only [needs to be written](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) as [`cast(proc as decimal)`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9c9d/8)

Answer (score 1):

There's something fundamentally wrong with your table design. Instead of using values like `'80.0 proc'` in a `VARCHAR` column, you should just keep `80.0` in a column of type `REAL` (or any suitable numerical type that's appropriate for your data). You could do dynamic conversion, only to be used in the `ORDER BY` expression, but this is also likely to deteriorate the performance of your query.

<strike>Adding "*proc*" to your text here doesn't seem useful, and it will also prevent you from doing a simple conversion.</strike>

Surprisingly (see *che*'s answer), apparently, `convert(..., decimal)` is capable of ignoring the trailing rubbish. It's not something you should rely on in general, though.

The [documentation on this aspect of the conversion](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/type-conversion.html) isn't particularly clear. It's worth reading that section to be aware of the limitations of string/numbers (which would happen in general), for example:

> ```
> mysql> SELECT '18015376320243459' = 18015376320243459;
>         -> 0
> ```

---

If that behaviour changed, you could probably use `replace()` in this case, just to get rid of `' proc'`.

For something more complex, you could potentially use a regular expression replacement to extract the numerical value from your string and cast it into a number before sorting, but [this is not supported out of the box in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/986826/372643) and that would be rather clunky anyway (fix the problem at its source: your column data type).

To deal with your legacy data, you could add an extra column and use an external program (in any language that's capable of doing a regexp replace), which shouldn't be too difficult.

Answer (score 1):

If you always have the same number of decimal points, my approach would be:

```
SELECT `proc` FROM `table` ORDER BY LENGTH(proc) DESC, proc DESC;
```