# MySQL order by string with numbers

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, collation

I have strings such as `M1 M3 M4 M14 M30 M40` etc (really any int 2-3 digits after a letter)
When I do " ORDER BY name " this returns:

`M1, M14, M3, M30, M4, M40`

When I want:

`M1, M3, M4, M14, M30, M40`
Its treating the whole thing as a string but I want to treat it as string + int

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/153642/1013082

Comment: Will there always only be one letter at the beginning of the string?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12257917/2008111

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use SUBSTR and CAST AS UNSIGNED/SIGNED within ORDER BY:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY
    SUBSTR(col_name FROM 1 FOR 1),
    CAST(SUBSTR(col_name FROM 2) AS UNSIGNED)
```

Comment: works great thanks! Just changed FROM 1 FOR 2 to FROM 1 FOR 1 and works

Comment: @rocky what to do if there is no fix formate, possible string likes:
test1,1test,te2st,test11,2131,10t,t22g

Answer (score 4):

If there can be multiple characters at the beginning of the string, for example like `'M10', 'MTR10', 'ABCD50', 'JL8', etc...`, you basically have to get the substring of the name from the first position of a number.

Unfortunately MySQL does not support that kind of REGEXP operation (only a boolean value is returned, not the actual match).

You can use this solution to emulate it:

```
SELECT   name
FROM     tbl
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ASCII(SUBSTRING(name,1)) BETWEEN 48 AND 57 THEN
                   CAST(name AS UNSIGNED)
              WHEN ASCII(SUBSTRING(name,2)) BETWEEN 48 AND 57 THEN
                   SUBSTRING(name,1,1)
              WHEN ASCII(SUBSTRING(name,3)) BETWEEN 48 AND 57 THEN
                   SUBSTRING(name,1,2)
              WHEN ASCII(SUBSTRING(name,4)) BETWEEN 48 AND 57 THEN
                   SUBSTRING(name,1,3)
              WHEN ASCII(SUBSTRING(name,5)) BETWEEN 48 AND 57 THEN
                   SUBSTRING(name,1,4)
              WHEN ASCII(SUBSTRING(name,6)) BETWEEN 48 AND 57 THEN
                   SUBSTRING(name,1,5)
              WHEN ASCII(SUBSTRING(name,7)) BETWEEN 48 AND 57 THEN
                   SUBSTRING(name,1,6)
              WHEN ASCII(SUBSTRING(name,8)) BETWEEN 48 AND 57 THEN
                   SUBSTRING(name,1,7)
         END,
         CASE WHEN ASCII(SUBSTRING(name,1)) BETWEEN 48 AND 57 THEN
                   CAST(SUBSTRING(name,1) AS UNSIGNED)
              WHEN ASCII(SUBSTRING(name,2)) BETWEEN 48 AND 57 THEN
                   CAST(SUBSTRING(name,2) AS UNSIGNED)
              WHEN ASCII(SUBSTRING(name,3)) BETWEEN 48 AND 57 THEN
                   CAST(SUBSTRING(name,3) AS UNSIGNED)
              WHEN ASCII(SUBSTRING(name,4)) BETWEEN 48 AND 57 THEN
                   CAST(SUBSTRING(name,4) AS UNSIGNED)
              WHEN ASCII(SUBSTRING(name,5)) BETWEEN 48 AND 57 THEN
                   CAST(SUBSTRING(name,5) AS UNSIGNED)
              WHEN ASCII(SUBSTRING(name,6)) BETWEEN 48 AND 57 THEN
                   CAST(SUBSTRING(name,6) AS UNSIGNED)
              WHEN ASCII(SUBSTRING(name,7)) BETWEEN 48 AND 57 THEN
                   CAST(SUBSTRING(name,7) AS UNSIGNED)
              WHEN ASCII(SUBSTRING(name,8)) BETWEEN 48 AND 57 THEN
                   CAST(SUBSTRING(name,8) AS UNSIGNED)
         END
```

This will order by the character part of the string first, then the extracted number part of the string as long as there are <=7 characters at the beginning of the string. If you need more, you can just chain additional `WHEN`s to the `CASE` statement.

Comment: its worked but how to order if its have number values like:  'M10', '40', 'MTR10', 'ABCD50','8', 'JL8','55'

Comment: Its need to add ORDER BY name*1, CASE.. before the first CASE to work if its have clean numbers between mixed string with numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get this working for my issue which was sorting MLS Numbers like below:

V12345
V1000000
V92832

The problem was V1000000 wasn't being valued higher than the rest even though it's bigger.

Using this solved my problem:

```
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTR(col_name FROM 2) AS UNSIGNED) DESC
```

Just removed the `SUBSTR(col_name FROM 1 FOR 1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
order by name,SUBSTRING(name,1,LENGTH(name)-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It split number and letters as separately.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col,'1', 1), '2', 1), '3', 1), '4', 1), '5', 1), '6', 1)
, '7', 1), '8', 1), '9', 1), '0', 1) as new_col  
FROM table group by new_col;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try remove the character with SUBSTR. Then use ABS to get the absolute value from field:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ABS(SUBSTR(field,1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method i used in my project is:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY LENGTH(col_name) DESC, col_name DESC LIMIT 1
```