# PHP Select between two strings

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, between

I've the following mysql table :

Table Name : `items`

```
item_no qty
1l1000bk 1
1l1020be 2
1l900bk 12
1l820be 19
```

After creating a `form` that submits to other page which contains the following PHP code:

```
$from = $_POST['from'];
$to = $_POST['to'];

$length = max(strlen($from), strlen($to)); 

$query6 = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE SUBSTRING(item_no, 1, ".$length.")   BETWEEN '".$from."' AND '".$to."' ORDER BY item_no Desc";

$result6 = mysql_query($query6);
if(!$result6){
    mysqli_error();
    exit();
}



if(mysql_num_rows($result6)>0){
$num6 = mysql_num_rows($result6);

for($i=0;$i<$num6;$i++){    

$row6 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result6);
echo $row6['item_no']."</br>";
}
}
```

The output is completely wrong, accoring to the select statment..I need to output the searched item_no as Descending order !..
Here what it shows :

```
1l900bk
1l820be
1l1020be
1l1000bk
```

How come 1l1000 is smaller than 1l900 ? It seems that it only compares the 3rd character ?..How to make sure it compares the full string?

Please Help !

Comment: It compares the whole string. To compare the value you want, see this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097368/mysql-order-by-string-with-numbers

Answer (score 0):

```
         SELECT column_name(s)
         FROM table_name
         WHERE column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value2;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because it is sorted as a string, not as an integer.
If you want to sort is, you should make shure all numbers are alike: so if you have 1000 and 900, use 0900. then it will sort ok.