# How to apply Order By on text with digit entry

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, technical-debt

Here is my test data (MySQL)

```
test1
test2
test3
test10
test11
mytest
```

I want to Order these record by text, and than by following number (if present):

```
mytest
test1
test2
test3
test10
test11
```

And When I use `Order By`, my data is sorted as text, like so:

```
mytest
test1
test10
test11
test2
test3
```

Could anyone provide me a solution?

Comment: Do you always have number at the end? Have you seen this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097368/mysql-order-by-string-with-numbers ? Here is also good explanation of the way of doing it: http://www.copterlabs.com/blog/natural-sorting-in-mysql/

Comment: Dear Stepashka, Actually not sure that some time i have alphabetic record and some time both alphanumeric+alphabetic so in that case what i will do. Like the bellow.    asdasda
Faisal Town
Gulshan ravi
new sector
Sector Hills
sector1
sector2
sector3
sector4
sector10
sector9     Thanks

Comment: So the string `sector` is static ?

Comment: Clearified question.

Answer (score 0):

In my query I am dividing alphanumeric values from string values, then combing the result,take a look :

```
  select temp1.a col from
  (select a from tabl WHERE a not REGEXP '[0-9]' order by length(a)) temp1
  union all 
  select temp2.a  from
  (select a FROM tabl WHERE a REGEXP '[0-9]' order by length(a),a) temp2 ;
```