# mysql order by of unpatterned string with numbers at the end

Tags: mysql, sql, string

For example I have `table1` that has column named "Column1" and it has the ff values: `item 1, item 2, item 10, old item 3.5, old item 20.1`
when I use `SELECT Column1 FROM table1 ORDER BY Column1 ASC` the result is:

```
-----------------
|Column1        |
-----------------
| item 1        |
| item 10       |
| item 2        |
| old item 20.1 |
| old item 3.5  |
```

is there a way that I can make it like this?

```
-----------------
|Column1        |
-----------------
| item 1        |
| item 2        |
| item 10       |
| old item 3.5  |
| old item 20.1 |
```

I see the post from [MySQL order by string with numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097368/mysql-order-by-string-with-numbers) but it only has a fixed pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The content of the column is sorted as varchar.
i suggest you to divide the string into two columns. (C1 = Varchar // C2 = number) 
f.ex.:
R1C1: item
R1C2: 1
R2C1: item
R2C2: 10
and so on.

After that you're able to order by C2.

Another solution is to split the content of C1 by a regular Expression and then ordering by the result of the regex.