# Magento Name Sorting

Tags: magento, sorting

Im having some difficulties in understanding magento's sorting by NAME.
I have lots of products with names like the following and i dont understand why they appear like so :

```
Lorem ipsum #1 Alabama
Lorem ipsum #1 Cristiana
Lorem ipsum #10 Jack
Lorem ipsum #14 Connor
Lorem ipsum #2 Washington
Lorem ipsum #2 Kent
Lorem ipsum #1 Pall Mall
Lorem ipsum #1 Disease
```

Shouldn't all the products starting with **Lorem ipsum #1**  be displayed first? 
Well,name sorting seems to have flaws since on my website they appear exactly like in the example from above where some products starting with **Lorem ipsum #2** appear in front of other products that are starting with **Lorem ipsum #1**.

Can someone explain me why is this happenig and how to correct it? 
Much appreciation.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally the records would be retrieved from the DB using natural case sorting, but this is not possible in MySQL from what I know, outside of [the curious case described in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153633/natural-sort-in-mysql). To correct it you will need to change how the CatalogSearch module forms its queries.

Comment: Yesterday i got by this problem by paying more attention to getProductCollection's sorting. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You should answer your question so others may benefit - I've seen this question before on Magento forums.

Comment: Im the same user having the same problem. I asked the question in both sites in order to have more chances of getting an answer. I really dont remember what changes i did to make it work.