# mysql natural sort the given data

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by, natural-sort

I have data in the following format :

```
AC-1234/12
AC-4321/12
ANA-4532/12
231
IHC-543/12
F-125/12
F-345/12
ds-234/12
```

I want to do a natural sort on this in mysql.

the result should be as such :

```
AC-1234/12
AC-4321/12
ANA-4532/12
F-125/12
F-345/12
ds-234/12
231
```

tried some of the mysql natural sorting tricks but didn't work for me.Suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I tried this :

```
select column 
from table_name 
Order By LENGTH(column), column
```

Comment: What do you mean by natural sort??

Comment: Natural join has nothing to do with natural sorting.

Comment: i meant natural sorting sorry

Comment: Try it this way: `ORDER BY column ASC`

Comment: Why would a sort allow `F-345/12` to be above `ds-234/12`?

Comment: @GiantofaLannister I guess lower case would come after uppercase.

Comment: In the results, the line 'IHC-543/12' does not appear, error on copy/paste I guess?

Comment: Check this SO question [Natural Sort in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153633/natural-sort-in-mysql) and its answers, can bring some light into your question. On MySQL natural sort seems tricky to get using plain sql and must rely on either functions or just adding a rank column on your table.

Comment: Whhaa...Just found this other link about natural sorting.. ROLF... [CodingHorror: Sorting for Humans : Natural Sort Order](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order.html)

Comment: non of that seems to works. Lets say there are two more records AC-100/12 and AC-12/12 then AC-100/12 come first. 
This is what i got using the sql fiddle shown below.

Comment: sorting these strings numerically as well is required

Comment: As commented before, natural sort is tricky, your best option is to add a column to use it as rank on a `ORDER BY` clause. A `CREATED_ON` column will do the trick too. If not, then you must rely on functions as you can see on the answers to the SO question I linked on my 2nd comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `CASE` expression to do  this like so:

```
SELECT column
FROM  Tablenametemp 
ORDER BY
   CASE 
     WHEN column REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+$' THEN 1 --If column is number 
     ELSE 0 
   END, column
```

### [Here is a SQL fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65e56/9)

Answer (score 0):

i have similar problems, will you guys check mine ?

[MySQL Order By Alpha Numeric Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50037699/mysql-order-by-alpha-numeric-not-working/50038031#50038031)

and my sql fiddle

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7773a6/1