# MySQL Order By Alpha Numeric Not Working

Tags: mysql, sorting

Here's the case, I use a MySQL query like this

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    tbl_name
WHERE
    id = 1
ORDER BY LENGTH(title), title;
```

but when there are titles like

Detective Conan Episode 797.5 English Subbed

Detective Conan Episode 829.2 English Subbed

**It becomes**

Detective Conan Episode 897 English Subbed

Detective Conan Episode 898 English Subbed

Detective Conan Episode 797.5 English Subbed

Detective Conan Episode 829.2 English Subbed

**The correct one must be like this**

Detective Conan Episode 797.5 English Subbed

Detective Conan Episode 829.2 English Subbed

Detective Conan Episode 897 English Subbed

Detective Conan Episode 898 English Subbed

Is it possible in a MySQL query to sort like what I want? or should I redesign the table structure and split the episode number in a new column.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood your initial request. Try this :

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    tbl_name
WHERE
ORDER BY CAST(title AS UNSIGNED), title;
```

Check fiddle example here : 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/755b97/2

Edit : This seems to work only when numbers are at the front.

This seems to be the only working solution for your problem, but at the cost of heavy load : [Natural Sort in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153633/natural-sort-in-mysql/12257917#12257917)

Other solution would be for you to switch to mysql 8.0, which introduces regexp_replace, allowing you to extract the numbers from your string, then ORDER BY CAST(the_result_of_your_regexp). Would still be heavy though.

Comment: I edited in the same time you commented. Check it out

Comment: if use, ORDER BY LENGTH(title) DESC, title;

Comment: Urahara Episode 10 English Subbed
Urahara Episode 11 English Subbed
Urahara Episode 12 English Subbed
Urahara Episode 1 English Subbed
Urahara Episode 2 English Subbed

Comment: if use ORDER BY LENGTH(title) without desc, it becomes ASC but correct

Answer (score 0):

@Aurelien its working become descending if i use:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    tbl_name
WHERE
    id = 1
ORDER BY LENGTH(title) DESC, title DESC
```

but there's still something wrong if the title like in the picture

[image: Check this]

Comment: Remove the DESC on your title. Keep it only on the LENGHT(title). Like in my answer.

Comment: i try in this stackoverflow not working with the image

Comment: ORDER BY LENGTH(title) DESC, title DESC
the result like this

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2804502&s=9#.WuGMw9Nub-Y

Comment: ORDER BY LENGTH(title) DESC, title;
the result like this

http://i68.tinypic.com/11jxbmh.png

Comment: I edited my initial (and most likely final on this post) answer with further info