# How to make ascending order in php

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have select query for the ascending order like...

```
select DISTINCT
    (m.task_name) as TaskName, 
    m.activity_name as ActivityName,
    m.actual_score,
    m.score,
    m.section_name 
from 
    users u, 
    som_scores m 
where 
    m.ref_student_id = '".$row['userid']."' and 
    m.section_name IN('jws1','jws2','jws3','jws4','sm1','srs1','Pws1','Pws2','lws1','sp1') 
ORDER BY 
    m.section_name ASC
```

I want to set the Section name in ascending order and also make the task name order by like Task1 Task2 and so on..

Means I want to display data like

1) sections name = jws1 and under the section like task
   Task1 Task2 Task3 Task4

2) sections name = jws2 and under the section like task
   Task1 Task2 Task3 Task4

And so on..

Comment: Your SQL Dump please... Even a sample would be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found solution like this way "`cast( SUBSTRING(TaskName, 5 ) AS unsigned ) ASC`"**

```
select DISTINCT
        (m.task_name) as TaskName, 
        m.activity_name as ActivityName,
        m.actual_score,
        m.score,
        m.section_name 
    from 
        users u, 
        som_scores m 
    where 
        m.ref_student_id = '".$row['userid']."' and 
        m.section_name IN('jws1','jws2','jws3','jws4','sm1','srs1','Pws1','Pws2','lws1','sp1') 
    ORDER BY 
        m.section_name ASC,
        cast( SUBSTRING(TaskName, 5 ) AS unsigned ) ASC,
        ActivityName ASC
```

Comment: This is overkill. Any indexes set on that field(s) will be ignored.

Comment: Looks like you only "solve" self-made problems here. Better is to prevent the problems first-hand.

Answer (score 2):

Just add secondary order in `ORDER BY`

```
ORDER BY 
    section_name ASC,
    TaskName ASC
```

Comment: but using this code i get the answer like                         Task 1 
Task 11
Task 12
Task 3
Task 4 This sequence i get the data

Comment: It would be best if you had a numeric field with the task number, instead of a "Task #" string. But see [Natural Sort in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153633/natural-sort-in-mysql) for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

use this query

```
select DISTINCT(m.task_name) as TaskName, m.activity_name as ActivityName,m.actual_score,m.score,m.section_name from users u, som_scores m where m.ref_student_id = '".$row['userid']."' and m.section_name IN('jws1','jws2','jws3','jws4','sm1','srs1','Pws1','Pws2','lws1','sp1') ORDER BY m.section_name ASC,m.task_name ASC
```

This will order by section first and after that by task name

try this order

```
m.task_name+0 ASC
```

OR

```
ORDER BY m.section_name ASC,CAST(SUBSTRING(m.task_name,LOCATE(' ',m.task_name)+1) AS SIGNED) ASC
```

Comment: but using this code i get the answer like                         Task 1 
Task 11
Task 12
Task 3
Task 4 This sequence i get the data