# MySQL order varchar alpha-numerically

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

Given a VARCHAR column called title with the following `SELECT title FROM table ORDER BY title` results:

```
Alpha 11
Alpha 2
Beta 1
Beta 11
Beta 2
```

I would like this to be in the "correct" order of

```
Alpha 2
Alpha 11
Beta 1
Beta 2
Beta 11
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: alter your table to have two columns for that, Field1 which contains *ALPHA*, *BETA*,.. and `Field2` which contains the numeric part. and you can now easily sort it, `ORDER BY Field1 ASC, Field2 ASC` becomes life easier.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT title ,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(title, '', 1) as title_str,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(title, ' ', -1) + 0 as title_num
FROM table 
ORDER BY title_str, 
  title_num
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called Natural Order sorting. Unfortunately there is no such sort algorithm built-in to MySQL, so your most reliable bet would be to create a UDF to do it for you.

However, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153633/natural-sort-in-mysql) has an interesting answer:

> Here is a quick solution:
>
> ```
> SELECT title
> FROM table
> ORDER BY LENGTH(title), title
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT title 
FROM tablename 
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(title, ' ', 1), 
         CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(title, ' ', -1)  AS UNSIGNED);
```