# PHP's natural sort memory issue on huge amount of data

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, memory, natural-sort

I'm using php's natural sorting algorithm `natsort` but I have a consideration about memory usage.

This is how it goes. Script pulls data from mysql and put results into an array and than apply `natsort` over it. But here is the catch. Row's text can be long and there could be hundreds of rows.

Example code:

```
$array = array();
while ($row = $db->getResults()) {
  $array[$row->code] = $row->text;
}

if (empty($array)) {
  uksort($array, "strnatcmp");
}
```

I wonder how is this affecting memory? Is this appropriate approach or should I do something more efficient, more memory pleasant?

Comment: @Jack Can MySQL do natural sorting in an efficient way?

Comment: Exactly. I am avoiding mysql natsort cos it's not supported natively. So I prefer php's natsort.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Well, then *that* should be the question shouldn't it? :)

Comment: @Jack, MySQL does not have a good solution for a natural sort.. have a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153633/natural-sort-in-mysql)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson it depends on your input data. You would have to produce a workaround to sort naturally.

Comment: @cbuckley And that workaround is?

Comment: Check this answer out; it might work for you too; http://stackoverflow.com/a/6344044/1338292

Comment: @Jack I've already tested this one. It works pretty well but sometimes it fails. So it's unreliable.

Comment: Or you just create an extra column so that mysql *can* sort reliably.

Comment: @Jack I agree, an extra sort column sounds like the best solution, provided there is a way to generate that column automatically.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson If you're in control of writing and reading this data from the same code, it should not be a problem; although, it's not exactly clean, I would have to admit.

Comment: Here is the the working solution by @Richard Toth: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153633/natural-sort-in-mysql/12257917#12257917

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is store a new column which duplicates the column you want to sort, but stores it in a transformed format that will sort naturally when using the regular sort algorithm.

Conceptually, you can do this by left-padding digit sequences with zeros to a length that will be as long as the longest possible numeric sequence that could occur in your string.

My solution isn't totally rugged, but if your strings just have digit sequences of known maximum lengths, then you can left pad them with zeros to that known max length. For example, if you had cd track titles with the track number embedded into the title like:

```
1 Foo
2 Bar
...
10 Baz
```

Maybe you decide that the longest numeric sequence possible would be 3(999 possible tracks), so you would pad the numeric sequences like

```
001 Foo
002 Bar
...
010 Baz
```

This works fine with strings that have multiple numeric sequences.

Sample php code, although you could write a mysql stored function to do this, and then use insert and update triggers on the table so that it's maintained transparently.

```
$input = 'a44b1c399d4';
$nat = preg_replace_callback('#\d+#', function($m) {
    return str_pad($m[0], 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}, $input);
echo $nat; // a044b001c399d004
```

Then just sort in mysql via

```
order by natsort_column
```

This also lets you put an index on that column, giving you good sort performance.

Comment: If I am correct than I should get results from mysql, add another column to the output and again query sql with that field? Could you give an example of mysql procedure to apply this code in first query?

Comment: @rambo.coder: Do you have an example of the above code for mysql also?

Comment: No, but you can write it simple enough using a stored fuction. just use a loop in it, with mysql string functions like locate() concat() substr()

Comment: @rambo.coder: Thanks, but I just found a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12257917/384864

Comment: @rambo.coder: Oh and your solution breaks if you do not have structured columns.

Comment: @BorutTomazin What is a "structured column"?

Comment: You have structured column in you example - string following numbers. That's not the case in my problem. I have column with different formats for example "19.45c", "001", "d135-3". How can I sort that kind of "unstructured" data with your solution?

Comment: This is brilliant. I'm going to be using this to naturally sort product SKUs. I can easily store the "padded SKU" along with the normal SKU and then have MySQL alpha sort on that. Should work great. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the MySQL `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, and `ORDER BY` clauses so you don't waste time at the PHP level parsing thousands of unneeded records.

Comment: I know that but how can I apply natsort in mysql?

Comment: The important thing is to *limit* the results to only the records you need. As long as you have the records limited you can sort them in PHP just fine, probably not as fast as a MySQL stored proc, but fast enough since you shouldn't be fetching very many rows. If you *are* fetching hundreds like you say then 1) there is a problem with the design of your application, 2) it's an admin reports page a that doesn't run often and so not a big deal, 3) you need to limit the results to only the columns you need, or 4) need to implement caching once the results are ordered.

Comment: @Xeoncross Limiting results and sort later in the general case is non trivial, since to get for example the correct 50 records, you'd need to sort to know which they are. There may be application specific ways of doing it, in which case I agree completely that things should be limited in the database.

Comment: @Xeoncross I absolutely agree with you. But how can I know where is the limit applying sort within PHP?