# MySQL Natural Sort (like OSX Finder)

Tags: mysql, natural-sort

I've searched for this for a long time, but the solutions I've found aren't working as I need.

Let me explain: I have a table containing a couple of thousands of products, each one with an alphanumeric SKU, used also for sorting.
This SKU consists of:

`Category Code` (variable number of alphabetic characters),

`Product Number` (integer),

`Product Model Variation` (optional, variable number of alphabetic characters)

For example: `MANT 12 CL` (without spaces)

---

Now, I need to get them ordered like this (and if these were filenames, OSX Finder would order them perfectly):

```
MANT1
MANT2
MANT2C
MANT2D
MANT2W
MANT3
MANT4C
MANT9
MANT12
MANT12C
MANT12CL
MANT12P
MANT13
MANT21
MANT24
MANT24D
MANT29
```

Of course `ORDER BY sku` is plainly wrong:

```
MANT1
MANT12
MANT12C
MANT12CL
MANT12P
MANT13
MANT2
MANT21
MANT24
MANT24D
MANT29
MANT2C
MANT2D
MANT2W
MANT3
MANT4C
MANT9
```

And `ORDER BY LENGTH(sku), sku` has problems sorting the model variations:

```
MANT1
MANT2
MANT3
MANT9
MANT12
MANT13
MANT21
MANT24
MANT29
MANT2C
MANT2D
MANT2W
MANT4C
MANT12C
MANT12P
MANT24D
MANT12CL
```

So, is there a way to sort this stuff like Finder would?

(Also, once sorted, is there a way to get the next and previous product? I don't mind using several queries: at this point elegance is the last of my problems...)

Thanks everybody in advance.

---

One last thing: during my searches I've found [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12257917/653245)
but I have no idea how to use it in PHP, so I don't know if it works and is actually an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using PHP when fetching data?

If so, try using [natural sort function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) for in memory sort after data is already loaded?

Comment: Oh man, it was so simple yet I spent dozens of days and `natsort()` never occurred to me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The order is not 'plain wrong', it simply depends what collation you use. In your case, you might try the binary collation, for example, 'latin1_bin'.

Following example the ORDER BY using COLLATE for UTF8 data:

```
mysql> SELECT c1 FROM t1 ORDER BY c1;
+------+
| c1   |
+------+
| a1   |
| a12  |
| a13c |
| a2   |
| a21  |
+------+

mysql> SELECT c1 FROM t1 ORDER BY c1 COLLATE 'utf8_bin';
+------+
| c1   |
+------+
| a1   |
| a12  |
| a2   |
| a21  |
| a13c |
+------+
```

Comment: This actually doesn't work as I need: `a2` should come after `a1` and `a13c` should come after `a12`, but thanks anyway!