# Natural sorting technique in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by, substring

I have having trouble performing natural sort in mysql. I am a mysql noob and maybe this is adding to the problem

I have a list of buses numbers at  a website I work on

List was at first random

bus_name

```
F1
F22
F10
F15
F7
F90
```

I attempted to do a natural sort using this

```
mysql> SELECT version
-> FROM version_sorting
-> ORDER BY CAST(version AS UNSIGNED), version;
```

taken from http://www.mpopp.net/2006/06/sorting-of-numeric-values-mixed-with-alphanumeric-values/

However I have the following now

```
F1
F10
F15
F22
F7
F90
```

As I note I believe the issue above has something to do with an imaginary zero that mysql attaches with each string , thereby making F7 as F70 which is > F22

I would want my list to be like

```
F1
F7
F10
F15
F22
F90
```

Can you people help me here please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you try this?

```
SELECT version
FROM version_sorting
ORDER BY LENGTH(version),  version;
```

Comment: Nice use of Length I never thought of that.

Comment: @TinTran in this case, both mine and Saharsh's query work correctly. But some situation, I guess only `LENGTH(..)` would work like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153633/natural-sort-in-mysql

Comment: Perfect. Worked without alteration . Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT vs.version
FROM version_sorting vs
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(vs.version,2) AS SIGNED), vs.version;
```