# how to sort varchar numeric columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I write ...
`ORDER BY` column `ASC`
but my column is `VARCHAR` and it sorts wrong like

I want to sorting numeric value but its datatype is varchar then how
value like this

```
1.2.840.113619.2.55.3.163578213.42.1355218116.691.1
1.2.840.113619.2.55.3.163578213.42.1355218116.691.10
1.2.840.113619.2.55.3.163578213.42.1355218116.691.100
1.2.840.113619.2.55.3.163578213.42.1355218116.691.101
1.2.840.113619.2.55.3.163578213.42.1355218116.691.2
1.2.840.113619.2.55.3.163578213.42.1355218116.691.20
```

but i want to in sequence last

```
1.2.840.113619.2.55.3.163578213.42.1355218116.691.1
1.2.840.113619.2.55.3.163578213.42.1355218116.691.2
1.2.840.113619.2.55.3.163578213.42.1355218116.691.10
1.2.840.113619.2.55.3.163578213.42.1355218116.691.20
1.2.840.113619.2.55.3.163578213.42.1355218116.691.100
1.2.840.113619.2.55.3.163578213.42.1355218116.691.101
```

and also I have string like this

```
1.2.840.114257.0.10325113632288210457800001002296133400001
1.2.840.114257.0.10379710976288210457800000002296491200000
1.2.840.114257.0.10328923264288210457800000002296158400001
```

I also want to sort this ...

Comment: Only last digits you would like to sort?

Comment: That's called [Natural Sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153633/natural-sort-in-mysql).

Comment: No I want to sort whole string

Comment: i think you should redesign your schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your specific example, you can do:

```
ORDER BY length(col), col
```

If you have other examples, you might need to "parse" the values using `substring_index()`.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer ?

Answer (score 2):

I have tried the following and it is working fine.
First Remove the `"."` From the String so you have only numeric and then sort by using `ABC()` Function so, It will not truncated.

`SELECT yourcol AS v FROM test ORDER BY ABS(REPLACE(yourcol, '.', '')), yourcol;`

Answer (score 2):

I think you should redesign your schema,

If you have only digits in ur input than go for `@Gordon Linoff` answer
Or may your input also contain character string(`eg: ankit123`) and you want sort in order to that char and number also than you may go for this

You have to `implementing` any `Algorithm` like this

Lets take `eg`

```
1 >1.2.1
2 >1.2.10
3 >1.2.2
```

Now make all digits equal, Decide any `max` length(`eg`: 5) so attach 0 ahead to make all digits with same length

now above string look like

```
1 >00001.00002.00001
2 >00001.00002.00010
3 >00001.00002.00002
```

Now if you you fire  `ORDER BY` on this string you get your output in sorted order.

Comment: This string is predefine string we can not change in this string

Comment: you may take temp column store this changed value in that and call order by on that column

Comment: @ankit337: There was no need to edit your answer and recommend Gordon's. Your answer is perfect. The column doesn't contain numbers but strings built from number parts. So one must either redesign the db and store the separate numbers or apply an algorithm such as you describe. Yes, Gordon's answer works in case all numbers parts (except the last) have constant lengths.

Comment: `@Thorsetn kettner`
Yes,you are right but i think this guys want to sort column which contain only number, that's way i recommend Gordon's answer,It's worth in this case than me.