# Ordering varchar with numbers in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table like that:

```
id | prof
---------
1  | PROF1/2015
2  | PROF2/2015
3  | PROF10/2015
```

When I make:

```
SELECT prof FROM table ORDER BY prof ASC
```

I'm getting result:

```
PROF1/2015
PROF10/2015
PROF2/2015
```

But the result should be:

```
PROF1/2015
PROF2/2015
PROF10/2015
```

How to make this works?

Comment: Dynamic version will require two `SUBSTRING`s and `CAST` while static(for this result only) can achieved with `FIELD(prof, 'PROF1/2015','PROF2/2015','PROF10/2015')`).

Comment: What you are searching for is known as “Natural sorting”, where 10 does follow 9 and not 2. Possible duplicate of [Natural Sort in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153633/natural-sort-in-mysql), See also: http://www.copterlabs.com/blog/natural-sorting-in-mysql/

Comment: garbage in, garbage out - as they say!!

Comment: Natural Sort in MySQL works great, but how to count rows `where prof < PROF2/2015` and it counts only id 1, not 1 and 3?

Answer (score 0):

Hello try with this i hope this will work for you

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY (0+prof)>0 asc, (0+prof)=0 asc
```