# How to sort by numeric and alphanumeric items in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sorting, sql-order-by, numeric, alphanumeric

i want to sort a list that has numeric and alphanumeric items like this:

- PIEZA1
- 0001
- PIEZA20
- REF30
- 234
- REF2
- FDGSDFG
- PIEZA3
- REF0004
- REF2005

And this is how i want to stay:

- 0001
- 234
- FDGSDFG
- PIEZA1
- PIEZA3
- PIEZA20
- REF0004
- REF2
- REF30
- REF2005

But, when i use the 'order by' clause, the sort appears like this:

- 0001
- 234
- FDGSDFG
- PIEZA1
- **PIEZA20**
- PIEZA3
- REF0004
- REF2
- **REF2005**
- REF3

That order is because the sentence detects a string list, and the natural sort for strings mades it with alphabetical order

I don't know how to separate numeric with strings for sort, first with numeric and second with alphanumeric order

Comment: Could you send me wich is the duplicate question? I was finding a lot of questions, but none works

Comment: Try http://2kan.tumblr.com/post/361326656/postgres-natural-ordering

Answer (score 0):

Is a a natural Sort what yiou want ?  Try using `Order by Length(column), column`.

In Fact this is just the Short Version that does not always works as expected. If you want the REAL natural sort, use this: [Natural Sort in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153633/natural-sort-in-mysql/12257917#12257917)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to cast your alphanumeric column to **[bytea](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-binary.html)** datatype and try like this:

```
SELECT colname
FROM tablename
ORDER BY colname::bytea;
```

Comment: This solution i found it, but returns the same third list shown