# MySQL sorting alphanumeric correctly

Tags: sorting

My record id gives something like :

I can write query as

```
SELECT memberid 
FROM newmember_tbl 
ORDER BY memberid
```

Output:

```
 1. TNSFIT0002
 2. TNSFIT0003
 3. TNSFIT001
 4. TNSFIT0010 
 5. TNSFIT00103
 6. TNSFIT00104
```

in this TNSFIT00 is fixed. the remaining is string is i want to sorting in asceding.

I want to sort the following data items in the order they are presented below

```
 1. TNSFIT001
 2. TNSFIT0002
 3. TNSFIT0003
 4. TNSFIT0010
 5. TNSFIT00103
 6. TNSFIT00104
```

Comment: Have you considered including the query you are using? Try to show what you have done so far to resolve the question.

Comment: this will not help because you are looking for only 8 characters which is  `TNSFIT00` .remove LEFT(memberid,8) , and try .visit here for more info http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-left-function.php

Comment: using  ORDER BY memberid+0 it will shows as a TNSFIT0002 first, TNSFIT0003 second  and then TNSFIT001 as they continue

Comment: give a try to this:SELECT memberid FROM newmember_tbl ORDER BY memberid+00 ASC, memberid +0, memberid

Comment: i can write SELECT memberid FROM memberid ORDER BY RIGHT(memberid, 3); the result display is  correct. but i not confident  to this query because when id becomes to more than 1000 members it is work properly or not?

Comment: but the  BIN(memberid) column show all result is 0

Comment: but in your case length will work fine:SELECT memberid FROM newmember_tbl ORDER BY LENGTH(memberid), memberid

Comment: @Shilvant yes i checked it and you are right.i think it is not in mysql.

Comment: Thanku u Very much sir! SELECT memberid FROM newmember_tbl ORDER BY LENGTH(memberid), memberid is work  Very Well. So once again thanku @suchit Sir.

Comment: This question might be possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/153633/1025391

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using length:

```
SELECT memberid FROM newmember_tbl ORDER BY LENGTH(memberid), memberid
```

Comment: @Shilvant  then you can click the check and mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `order by` on the column that contains the `id` will accomplish this.

```
SELECT * FROM your_table_name ORDER BY id ASC
```