# More Complex ORDER BY (alpha first, then treat number as a whole number)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sorting

So I have a bunch of varchars that I need to sort in a certain way, first be alpha, and then treat the following number as a whole number (i.e. A2 would be before A10). That's the main problem, and then I have some with 'sub' letters after like A1M. Don't want to have to add a new column just for sorting, so I wanted to see if a more complex ORDER BY statement might be able to handle something like this.

They should be sorted like this:

```
A1
A1M
A2
A6
A6B
A9
A10
A15
A16
AS10
```

But it currently sorts like this (standard ORDER BY):

```
A1
A10
A15
A16
A1M
A2
A6
A6B
A9
AS10
```

Comment: Sorry @Barmar but I dont think that answer OP question. Selected answer say `I think this is why a lot of things are sorted by release date.`

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't do it, but some of the other answers do.

Comment: The others rely upon a fixed position for the number, I have no idea where the number part will start

Comment: @Barmar Im not sure if that is the way close questions should work. For example I know I can't call a duplicated if the question doesnt have a correct answer selected even when I know some answer are really good. So pointing duplicated to non correct answers in another post doesnt seem right. Instead you could use `share` function in the answer you think would help OP.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12257917/1491895). It shows how to find the position of the first digit in the column, then use that position to split the column into a prefix and suffix, so you can order by them separately. It would be better if you could fix the data to have the prefix and suffix in separate columns, this would allow them to be indexed.

Comment: This is known as ‘natural order’.

Answer (score 0):

If the first character is a letter followed by a number, you can do:

```
order by left(col, 1),
         substr(col, 2) + 0,
         col
```

The first key is the first letter.  The second is whatever number follows the letter.  The `+ 0` is an implicit conversion that does not return an error.  The final key is just the entire column.

Comment: The alpha part at the start is variable (between 1-4 characters), so there are ones like A1, but also ABCD123b

Comment: @Bryant You should update your question to show that case and how will that affect the result