# Laravel 5.3 Natural Sort attributes

Tags: laravel, sorting, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, natural-sort

I want to NatSort Eloquent model output. I have attributes like `Size 1/2`, `Size 3/4`, `Weight 1`, `Weight 2`, `Weight 10`...

In other words I want to natural sort strings but if there is fractions I want to sort them in ascending order too. (example: 3/8 is lower than 1/2)

`CategoryAttribute::where('category_id', $catId)->with('attributes')->get();`

I have `position` column in table and want to sort them and save as sorted positions. How can I make it the most performance friendly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153633/natural-sort-in-mysql

Comment: Actually you can just use [`$collection->sort('attributes')`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-sort). I've tried it and it seems to perform a natural sort. Double check it to be sure.

Comment: Can it perform mathematical calculations of 3/8, 1/2, 5/8, 3/4?

Comment: Nah not by default. I think your best bet would be to save fractions in a separate column.

Comment: But Many of them does not have fractions they have only numbers or only text. Only for fractions I don't think that it's a good idea to create column :/