# Is there a way to sort by a string filed that contains number, by the value of the number?

Tags: mysql

I have records with column record_id which is constructed from letters and numbers

eg

```
a1
a2
a11
a12
b1
```

If i sort this I would get

```
a1
a11
a12
a2
b1
```

i was wondering if there is a way to sort this by letter then by the value of the number as the following

```
a1
a2
a11
a12
b1
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153633/natural-sort-in-mysql

Comment: Thanks this would solve my problem indirectly

Comment: Sorry best I could do

Comment: I really appreciate it, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(string CHAR(3) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('a2'),('a11'),('a12'),('b1');

select * FROM my_table ORDER BY string;
+--------+
| string |
+--------+
| a11    |
| a12    |
| a2     |
| b1     |
+--------+

select * FROM my_table ORDER BY string+0;
+--------+
| string |
+--------+
| a2     |
| a11    |
| a12    |
| b1     |
+--------+
```

Now seriously consider normalising your data.

Comment: Thanks this works like charm, about you normalizing remark the table has many other columns I just took the column I wanted sorted